# Grafana graph total count shown as list?

Tags: elasticsearch, graph, kibana, grafana, dashboard

I have a Grafana dashboard, where I am currently getting my query shown as a "Gauge"-graph showing the total hits.

[image: Total hits, Gauge graph]

As you can see on the screenshot, it shows total number of hits - but I would like to have them on a list, with the details of each hit (NOT the Kibana way).

I've looked at some of the other graph models that Grafana provide and the "Table"-model is the one I find best, but it only shows the columns "time" and "count", which isn't that useful.

[image: Table showing only time and count]

Is there some way to manipulate the columns shown on the table, so it isnt "time" and "count" but more custom values?

Or do others have better ways to do it?

I have already looked at the tutorial/guidelines provided by Grafana [here](https://grafana.com/docs/features/panels/table_panel/) but I find them quite low on details.
I've also tried to pull out the "Raw document" to find the JSON-columns, that I want shown, but then it crashes and I get the same error message as the one reported in Grafans github [here](https://community.grafana.com/t/zabbix-dashboard-broken/21769) saying

> "Grafana has likely been updated. Please try reloading the page."

hmm... Quite frustrating to be honest.

// **In short**: I want to add some metrics from the query that is shown in the JSON, which I can place in the table, as I want.

**UPDATE 22nd Oct. 2019**
Regarding the error message from Grafana

> "Grafana has likely been updated. Please try reloading the page."

Updating it to the newest version 6.4.3 fixed this problem, even though it should have been fixed in 6.4.2.

This enables me to see raw JSON formatted data, so that is done. Now I need to find out how to fetch and work with some of these data inside the JSON, so that I can see them on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that I just had to use the metric "Unique Count" or "Count" from where I choose a indexed metric which will then give me a count value.

[image: showing the "count" option]

Please double check that you are not getting an average value, but a total. If it fx shows 0.4 and you only have integers, then you are probably getting an average value.

Also if you want to play around with the different metrics, so they show in the panel, a solution would be to choose the metric "Raw Document". Then inside visualization you can choose to add the metrics you want shown under "Column". Press the '+' mark and add the different metrics.

If you want to give it a better name, you can configure it under "Column Styles".

[image: showing how to configure Column Styles]

And finally - always **stay up to date** with the newest grafana version, so you don't end up getting frustated over a error which is only there because you haven't updated.